# How to fix MissingMethodException during Content.Load<Texture2D> in Xamarin Studio on MacOS X?

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monogame, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to create a simple program with MonoGame in Xamarin Studio 4.0.10 (build 5).
But when I try to load some textures using `Content.Load` method, I receive an exception `System.MissingMethodException` with a message

```cs
Method not found: 'MonoMac.AppKit.NSImage.AsCGImage'.
```

The actual lines of code I am using are:

```cs
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    //some stuff here

    Texture2D freezeTexts = new Texture2D[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        freezeTexts[i] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("freeze"+i); // exception here
    }

    //some other stuff here
}
```

I did some googling and found out that this happens because of some API changes, which Xamarin Studio haven't yet implemented (at least that's what I understood). So my question is: How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compile monomac from the latest source, to bring the API up to date.

It's pretty straightforward - this [blog](http://cocoa-mono.org/archives/80/exploring-cocoa-with-monomac-and-c-chapter-1-%E2%80%93-getting-started-%E2%80%93-part-2/) has some good instructions.

**EDIT**

It seems you need to go back in time with monomac to get a version compatible with the current release of MonoGame (which is pretty old - 3.0.1 was released on March 6th 2013).

It might be better to compile MonoGame itself from source. I managed to do this by forking their [repo](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame) and compiling the `MonoGame.Framework.MacOS` solution.

Referencing the assembly this produces in place of the released `MonoGame.Framework.dll` allows my test app to build and launch.

Comment: I followed the instructions to compile MonoMac.dll, then I added this as a reference to a project instead of existing MonoMac, but I still have the same exception. I hope I just need to find a specific commit to build?

Comment: @AntonGuryanov See my edit. I don't know if this is the recommended solution or not, but it should get you up and running

Comment: Thanks, now it is working! Just to mention, it is unnecessary to fork their repo, just clone and build.